# Weird MEX-file behavior

Tags: c, debugging, matlab, crash, mex

Something weird is happening. I created a MEX-file with MATLAB R2011, and I compiled it with Visual Studio 2010.

I'm able to use the MEX-file in the workspace correctly.
Then, I'm using the MEX-file inside a MATLAB m-file (calls the MEX-file several times). When I try to run it, MATLAB crashes and ask me close.

Trying to analyze the error, I put breakpoints, but when I put breakpoints in the m-file, everything is correct. Actually what I do to run all the m-file is put a breakpoint at the end of the function and runs ok, I also can finish the all m-file without errors.

But when I try to run it without the breakpoints, MATLAB crashes...

At first I thought that it could be the memory, but why it works correctly with breakpoints?

I would appreciate if you could give me a clue to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Jessica

Comment: some more links to documentation pages for debugging MEX-files: http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html#gen_debugging, http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f32489.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound like memory issue to me as well. Some code would help, as mentioned by Laurent'.

If you can reproduce the crash, I suggest debugging the c code itself. Make sure you run the debug version of the mex file, set a breakpoint in your code, attach to Matlab process from Visual Studio (ALt+Ctrl+p), and call the mex file from Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

I  also think that it is a memory issue.

Maybe, when you launch your mex file through the debugger, the memory is not handled exactly the same or the issue takes place just after your function returns.

You should try to launch matlab with [this environment](http://www.mathworks.fr/support/solutions/en/data/1-18CLQ/index.html?solution=1-18CLQ) to facilitate debugging.

Please note that memory corruption can make Matlab crash *after* the faulty Mex function.
This means that you're perhaps debugging the wrong function.

For further assistance, I would need to see your code ;)